# Are ID Requests on Doujins ontopic

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I am wondering, assuming the minimum stanard of quality was met, would a question asking to ID a Doujin be on topic? here is an example one:

> I am looking for a Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha Doujin i spotted while randomly searching for images on google
>
> The pages i saw i think were at the end and of it. it shows Presea pregnant (probably in her final trimester) and Alicia with her. Presea mono-logging saying how she's going to name her new baby after Fate so it seems to hint at being after the anime where Presea made it to Al-Hazard and was able to resurrect Alicia.
>
> I'd also want to know if it's Safe for Work (SFW) or Not Safe For Work (NSFW). if it's NSFW i'd like to know how Presea got pregnant.

If IDing Doujins are on topic, should we restrict the IDing to be be that of known series or should we also allow Original Doujins?

Comment: I think it's okay if the question is well written and has the necessary amount of info to uniquely ID the source, but your chances of actually getting an answer are pretty much zero.