# Are identifying fan-made works on-topic if they are from a known series?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, acceptable-questions

Years ago I asked this question on meta if [ID requests on doujins were on-topic](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/964/1587). The implied answer from the comment was that they were if the question was written well enough.

After that, we blacklisted ID request with the exception that we had to be iding something from within a series.

Recently, [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/42905/1587) was asked to ID a shounen ai/yaoi fanfiction that used *One Piece* as the setting.

Now considering that this is from a known series, would it still meet our exception for ID requests?

---

Also, would a doujin (which is too a fan-made) also be an exception to the rule if example pages were shown? (using the example from my previous question, if I had posted the page of Presea pregnant with Alicia with her rather than just described it)

Comment: It's a bit similar like the question asking for specific episodes. But I think the fact that it was from a doujin makes it even harder to answer than the usual id-req. But then again a harder question doesn't make it off topic

Comment: I don't think this is more answerable than a typical ID request. How many original, recognizable works are there sans fan-works? And how indistinguishable from each other are, on average, fan works to a given popular title? I feel like it's a level deeper into niche knowledge, and we're already out of our depth with regular IDs, so this would be even less answerable. Much less useful to any future site visitors!

Comment: Agree 100% with @Hakase. (Alternative approach: whenever somebody asks one of these questions, we just write a fanfic that conforms to all of their specifications and then link to it. Problem solved!)